# How can I get Android drawable name?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I get name of a drawable that was already set to an imageview?

I need to get the part that is after R.drawable.________

I've found that from Resources I can get resourceName, but it's just name of the imageview, not the drawable.

Comment: thats not possible

Comment: you can use tag in ImageView then use getTag()

Comment: @GaneshMB Do you mean set a tag to the ImageView with name of the drawable, and get it after?